# looking for specific errors in a log within the past hour

Tags: linux

I have a log that I need to audit every hour going back an hour. I currently run a command and just keep track of what I have accounted for in it's output but having an hourly audit would make things a lot easier. I've left off the additional grep filters for this output since I do not believe they are necessary.

How can I make this command output lines from the last hour up to now.

```
cat error.log | grep `date -u "+%Y-%m-%d"`| grep -i dangling*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-d` option to adjust the current time.

```
cat error.log | grep `date -d '-1 hour' -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H"` | grep -i dangling*
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date

Comment: @DomJangles if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.